# Calculate Uptime dynamically based on time interval chosen with SQL query for Grafana

Tags: mysql, dynamic, mariadb, grafana, gaps-and-islands

We have data stored in SQL (mariaDB) against time(15-min interval). Now this data determines the performance of an entity and it is secs (like number of secs within that 15min interval, it has issues wherein it can take any value from zero to 900). Now we are able to group them for any time interval period and plot the total impacted secs easily

Parameter_health Database contains two tables --

1. Parameter_detail table contains fixed data information against the parameter
2. Parameter_uasvalue table contains the un-available secs(UAS) for each 15 min interval against time for that parameter

Query used in Grafana for plotting the Bar graph with each value against total UAS for the given interval & it works perfectly fine ---

```
SELECT 
   parameter_detail.system, 
   parameter_detail.parameter_label, 
   sum(parameter_uasvalue.uas) as 'Total UAS'
FROM parameter_health.parameter_uasvalue 
left join parameter_health.parameter_detail on 
     parameter_detail.id=parameter_uasvalue.id
WHERE $__timeFilter(parameter_uasvalue.time) 
  and parameter_uasvalue.uas != '-1' and parameter_uasvalue.uas !=' 0' 
GROUP BY parameter_detail.system, parameter_detail.parameter_label
```

Now how do we use this value (Total UAS) to calculate the uptime of the parameter which would be $_timeFilter (chosen by grafana) minus 'Total UAS' divided by $_timeFilter * 100

But I am not sure how we can modify this query to work dynamically based on the varing $_timeFilter and calculate the uptime % of that Parameter and get it plotted in Bar graph
like if the time range is 0 to 4 hrs (for below data), then total secs is 14400 secs (16 intervals of 15 mins each) and now total UAS is 3230.
So uptime is ((14400 - 3230)/14400 )*100,

So question is how we use the __timeFilter variable to calculate this dynamically.

| id | time | uas |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Parameter-Unique Value1 | 15/11/2021 0:00 | 0 |
| Parameter-Unique Value1 | 15/11/2021 0:15 | 100 |
| Parameter-Unique Value1 | 15/11/2021 0:30 | 900 |
| Parameter-Unique Value1 | 15/11/2021 0:45 | 30 |
| Parameter-Unique Value1 | 15/11/2021 1:00 | 0 |
| Parameter-Unique Value1 | 15/11/2021 1:15 | 0 |
| Parameter-Unique Value1 | 15/11/2021 1:30 | 400 |
| Parameter-Unique Value1 | 15/11/2021 1:45 | 900 |
| Parameter-Unique Value1 | 15/11/2021 2:00 | 0 |
| Parameter-Unique Value1 | 15/11/2021 2:15 | 0 |
| Parameter-Unique Value1 | 15/11/2021 2:30 | 0 |
| Parameter-Unique Value1 | 15/11/2021 2:45 | 400 |
| Parameter-Unique Value1 | 15/11/2021 3:00 | 500 |
| Parameter-Unique Value1 | 15/11/2021 3:15 | 0 |
| Parameter-Unique Value1 | 15/11/2021 3:30 | 0 |
| Parameter-Unique Value1 | 15/11/2021 3:45 | 0 |
| Parameter-Unique Value1 | 15/11/2021 4:00 | 0 |

Comment: Try to read [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and try to use it when asking a question.